# Show image in img tag using image code using php

Tags: php, html, image

I want to show image in my web page using image code. I am new for this activity.
can anyone guide me for this?
my image code is as bellow :

```
"ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000001 00010000 ffe10058 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080002 01120003 00000001 00010000 87690004 00000001 00000026 00000000 0003a001 00030000 00010001 0000a002 00040000 00010000 00b7a003 00040000 00010000 01130000 0000ffdb 0043001f 15171b17 131f1b19 1b23211f 252f4e32 2f2b2b2f 5f444838 4e706376 746e636d 6b7c8cb2 977c84a9 866b6d9b d39da9b8 bec8cac8 7895dbea d9c2e9b2 c4c8c0ff db004301 2123232f 292f5b32 325bc080 6d80c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 ffc00011 08011300 b7030122 00021101 031101ff c4001f00 00010501 01010101 01000000 00000000 00010203 04050607 08090a0b ffc400b5 10000201 03030204 03050504 04000001 7d010203 00041105 12213141 06135161 07227114 328191a1 082342b1 c11552d1 f0243362 7282090a 16171819 1a252627 28292a34 35363738 393a4344 45464748 494a5354 55565758 595a6364 65666768 696a7374 75767778 797a8384 85868788 898a9293 94959697 98999aa2 a3a4a5a6 a7a8a9aa b2b3b4b5 b6b7b8b9 bac2c3c4 c5c6c7c8 c9cad2d3 d4d5d6d7 d8d9dae1 e2e3e4e5 e6e7e8e9 eaf1f2f3 f4f5f6f7 f8f9faff c4001f01 00030101 01010101 01010100 00000000 00010203 04050607 08090a0b ffc400b5 11000201 02040403 04070504 04000102 77000102 03110405 21310612 41510761 71132232 81081442 91a1b1c1 09233352 f0156272 d10a1624 34e125f1 1718191a 26272829 2a353637 38393a43 44454647 48494a53 54555657 58595a63 64656667 68696a73 74757677 78797a82 83848586 8788898a 92939495 96979899 9aa2a3a4 a5a6a7a8 a9aab2b3 b4b5b6b7 b8b9bac2 c3c4c5c6 c7c8c9ca d2d3d4d5 d6d7d8d9 dae2e3e4 e5e6e7e8 e9eaf2f3 f4f5f6f7 f8f9faff da000c03 01000211 0311003f 00b19eb4 72693bd2 e715e69d e3581eb4 ca909183 9a8f7814 d1485cd2 37ad0181 a5c03d0d 03114f51 4ea60e09 a750c181 e2941cf7 a3ad3738 a0438e71 d6929339 a5e9400b 9a01a6e6 941a007e 683c814d cd283c52 1587034a 0d3334a0 d2b0587e 68cd3734 668b1361 f9a4cd37 34668b05 87834522 d1482c33 bd213413 8269339a b2ac3189 27148571 413f39a7 70453d8b d8414872 18114a69 2801cfd8 d0a78a5c 82829838 24502241 4845028a 421a2969 31834b4c 6252d068 a005a514 94aa6908 3bd28a3b d28a4214 518a052d 21011494 1349400f 5a2901a2 908818f2 28191cf6 a4ee28dc 73ed5a1a d843c1cd 3c74a691 8fa53802 7a1a0043 49d29d83 8a6edf5a 00543c11 41e0e69c 00148c28 175014b4 d534ea42 03cd140a 28010d14 1a4a6316 94525148 079a01a4 cd20340a c3c52d34 1aad772e d9ed9075 69013446 3ccec437 6572d9a6 d29a4a45 0e5a2901 a290885c 60f1498f ce9ed8a6 f5ab4688 07229ca7 d3a54609 cf14f4ea 6860d0f3 4de69dda 9bda9225 0a2918f1 4134839a 63105283 4838cd28 a062e697 3c52639a 5c5210d2 69334a45 25318b9a 5078a402 940a0426 6968c669 39a0082d e6f32ee7 50785c01 f866a0b8 491f5588 81903047 3d81a7d8 41b1e57d c4e58afd 79eb52a7 3a931fee c607eb5b 68a4edd8 c2cdc55c 75fcbe55 b120f3b8 0fd7ff00 ad56322a 9ea51f99 0280c00d c3fc2ad2 a954504e 480013eb 59b4b951 6afccc70 eb4520eb 456650d6 19cd3706 9f9eb484 815450d0 bcd39570 734020d2 64f6a007 938a4269 393d69b9 228b0580 9eb403c0 34d39c9a 51ca914c ab0a4e68 14514843 bb538532 941a4215 864532a4 a611834d 02014ea6 d3a860c5 a46e067d 28a493fd 5b7fba68 5b8886cf 3f664cf5 6c93f9d3 6dce6f2e 5bdd47e9 4eb5c1b5 888fee8a 65972666 fef486b4 7f688ec3 af8e215f f7d6ad1e f54efcfe e93feba0 ab879a99 7c2817c4 c41d68a0 75a2a0b1 99c9a08a 4e99a0e4 1eb4ca17 818a3238 a6d2d301 770a0e08 a6d0093c 668b0584 6e99a14f 38a18522 f514c7d0 9074a314 8bde9d52 2128a5a3 140828eb 45250014 b4845283 400a2834 8294d211 4d924b46 2f082f0f 564f4fa5 436734cd 16c8a3c9 c925d8f0 2af5c36d b790e7f8 4d4361ff 001e71e3 be7f9d6e a5eedda3 2e5f7ac9 8b1db664 124ce646 1d07402a da93c834 c14f5ac6 4dbdcd2c 96c263e6 a29d8ef4 5485c889 c838a652 b37b5039 15668252 e6942123 ad326262 85dc63e5 19e685ae 826d21a5 f3208d7a fde6f614 bbf32151 d57a9f4a ab14a61b 27b86199 246e0ff9 fc6acda2 05b6539c 96f989f5 26b4946c 8ce33bb1 dcfad006 0d29e28a 8351475a 7d3053aa 5898b40a 2814085a 4a534948 418a08a0 52d031bd 29683473 4c0af7c0 1b39323a 723eb4b6 b188ed90 01d464fd 4d33516f f4461dc9 02ac0015 40ec062a fec5884b df147515 20a881e6 9e1866a1 a2da2414 535ba0c5 1524d880 f24d3929 31c93403 5668c93a 552d565d b6e101e5 cfe82ae0 358faa49 bee76f64 18aba4af 230aaed1 2179d9e0 8e2fe14c fe35b501 06de323a 6d1fcab0 2b5f4e94 3da85279 4e3f0ada ac74d0ca 8cbdeb32 c1a4cd29 39a415ce 760a29c0 d3694526 0c7d0290 1a514891 dda9b4e1 4d348414 b494b40c 4a28a298 152ffe6f 253fbd20 ab2dcd56 b9e6f6d9 7d096ff3 f9559356 f644c7e2 6369d494 f032054b 2d8f4e94 50bc5150 410f7a43 9a53de92 acd00356 1ccfbe67 7fef126b 6663b627 6f4526b0 eba28add 9cb887b2 12ac5a4f e44d93f7 4f06abd1 5b357563 993b3ba3 7f208c83 c5159f63 74001148 78fe127b 7b5680eb 5c928b8b 3d184d4d 5c5a052d 15050a29 d4d155cd d2457322 4a768c0d bc53516f 622524b7 2d8a0d41 f6cb6c67 ce5fd6a4 49125526 360c3da9 38b5ba12 927b31d4 52640ea6 96914145 14500546 f9b535ff 0062327f cfe7564d 568b9d46 63fdd503 f9559357 3e84c3ab 129ebd29 94e4a865 b245eb45 20eb4549 2447ad25 29ef4559 64178716 b21f6c7e b58b5b37 fc5a3fe1 fceb1aba a8ec71e2 3e20a28a 2b539c2b 42cef318 8e53c766 359f4b53 28a92b32 e1371774 7418a2b3 6cefb601 1cc72bd8 fa569020 ae41c83d 08ae4945 c59db09a 9a1b2c82 289a43fc 23f3ac49 64695cbb 9c935a5a 993f65e3 a6e19fd6 b3a011b4 ca262c10 f04af5ad e8a56b9c f5dbbd88 aa48a578 5c3a1c11 51d15b1c fb1b16ed 3dcc8934 80246b92 00ee7a55 ca8ad062 d2218c7c a2a5ae19 bbb3be0a c828a08a 31525952 d399ee5f d5f1fcea cd56d3f2 6066fef3 93564d5c fe2269fc 2253969b 4e5a865b 1e28a406 8a449193 cd148472 68ab2caf a87fc7a3 fe1fceb1 eb66f866 ce4fc3f9 d63574d2 f84e2c47 c4145145 6a601453 954b3055 0493d00a b8b64b1a 6fb87c01 d8526d22 a3072d8a 35620bb9 200429c8 f43d2a39 4a17cc6a 557d09cd 4745935a 8aee2f42 dcb7cf2c 65191307 eb55475a 2b52d6d2 17b552cb 92dce7d2 a5b5045a 52a8ccc7 fbedf5a7 40a1e644 6ce1980e 2a5bcb66 82439e54 9e0fad59 b1b35788 c920fbdf 7483c8a1 c925708c 1b958d25 50a00030 070297bd 26ee9eb4 a01cf35c 4ced0351 cceb1c4c cc71c1eb 505edf2d bfc89f34 9fa0ac87 91a4625d 8927d6b6 8526f566 33aa9688 d3b1b885 2048cbe1 8f6c1f5a b84562d9 297bb8c0 3d0e7f2a da345549 3d0aa326 d6a369cb 4def4e5a c99b31e2 8a051522 233d4d21 14eee692 a8a2bddf 36b20f6f eb58d5b7 723f7127 fba6b12b a68ec71e 23e20a5a 4a9ada3f 36e114f4 cf3f4ad9 e86095dd 8bd6b12d b41e749f 788cfd07 a5519ee1 e76cb1e3 b0ab3a9c 80b2a03c af26a8d6 7057f799 ad495bdc 42514558 86d2594f dd2abea6 adb4b732 49bd8af5 66d2e9e0 61ce533c 8a5bdb71 038dbf74 8fd6aad1 a490f583 3a170b2a 00406523 f3a6c508 8576a93b 3b03dbf1 a8f4f7df 68a3392b c1a65c5f a43f2a0d edfa0ae4 e595dc51 d9cd1b73 32d9c05c 93803b9a a571a905 f9201b9b fbddaa93 49717920 4c96cf45 1d05695a 59adbf27 e693d7d3 e955c918 6b2239dc f48ec52f b05d4ca6 520658e4 863834c9 6c64862f 31caf500 01cd6e0e 473552f9 4b889077 9067e94e 355b7625 d2495c2d ad52d94e 0ee63d49 a9a9cdde 92b16db7 76744524 ac86914e 02928148 a1c33452 8e68a421 87a9a4a5 ef495450 c9c66171 fec9fe55 855bec32 8c3d462b 00d7451d 99c988dd 0956f4d0 0dce4f65 3552ad69 fccac338 ca919ad6 5b18c3e2 4433bf99 33bfa926 a3a5a4aa 25bbb2d5 82a35c80 e33dc7d6 b56b1219 1a2903af 515b1e6a 08c3b305 52323358 554ee755 092b5826 89668ca3 7e07d0d6 52a886e7 6ccb900e 1aaec9a8 c438452d fa551b99 84f26fdb b4e31d69 d3525a32 6b4a0f55 b8095a16 758643b5 b8cfa8a6 22867019 c20ee4d3 6ad595aa 5c87dcc4 15c74ad5 b495cc12 72762f5a c96902e2 39173dc9 ea6a7fb4 c19ff5c9 ff007d55 5fecc87f bcff00a5 4173a734 519911b7 28ec7ad7 35a127b9 d379c56c 69adcc1d e64ffbe8 526a1f68 b758de30 5075debc fe07fcf3 5cfd5cb4 d4ee2d57 cb0c248b bc6e323f fad5a2a4 a2ee8c9d 5bee6a45 2f9f0972 9b1c1c36 3a13ed4e a8e2984d 1aba26c5 3d17d29e 2b09ee75 4360a050 692a4b24 534522d1 52219de8 a3bd1545 0b58128d b2b2fa13 5bd59175 11379281 eedfd6b7 a2f739b1 0ae910c0 9e6cc89e a715a6d1 088ccca3 00a71ec4 0aaf6701 570ec391 b48fa1ab 1a84de5c 2507de7e 3e82aa4d b92489a7 1518b6cc 8a28a2b6 39829c58 9c64938e 29b45001 45153456 d2cbf754 e3d4f028 ba5b8d26 f6220093 81d6b66c adbc88be 61f337de f6a6dad9 2c243b7c cffa0ab7 5cd52a5f 447552a5 cbab1401 e9f9d2fd 69052d73 9b19f3e9 9be5cc4c 154f507b 532dacd1 6ea4493e 70807b73 5a847a55 3b6e6e2e 5bfdbc56 f1a92716 64e9c799 163000c0 1c519a28 c5646e19 a438a28c 500286a2 900a281d 83b9a28e e68a002a 9cd1e6f5 b8fbf11f e5572a29 07fa4c4d fef0fd2a e0eccce6 ae84b5c1 b78ce39d b8fcab3e 7dd737e5 01efb47b 015a36e3 623274da c40fa75a a48047aa e3b127f5 15a45ead 99cd7bb1 45c16f12 c7b0202b efdea336 5013f731 f426acd2 1acd49f7 36e48f63 1ae1424e caabb403 c0a2081e 77c2f4ee 7d29f7ae b25c92a7 20719f5a d1b6458e dd00ee32 4d744a7c b1b9c90a 6a536848 ad618ba2 ee3ea79a 9e929472 2b99b6f7 3b14525a 0e14a29a 29d50028 a514de94 aa726810 f1daa958 730bbff7 a426adbb 011b927a 026abd82 e2ca3f7c 9fd6aa3a 4599fda4 4d494360 52039a46 a2d28008 3494e5e2 93062628 a0f5a280 1a7a9a2a a6268f88 e5dc3d1c 7f5a5fb4 4e3ac00f fbad5a72 76279fba 2d66908c 907d0e6a b7da64ff 009f739f f7850679 cf48957f de6cff00 2a395873 a2c10a85 9c9c0c73 9f6acf83 371a8194 0c2af3fe 1523c4f3 1fdf4a48 feea8c0a 9e32912e d45c0abf 857990d3 9357d89b 35535079 950041f2 1eac2a7f 347a5233 864618ea 08a88e8e e5cd5d59 18b566de f1a11b48 dcbe9e95 098641d5 1bf2a4f2 dffba7f2 aeb766ac ce14e517 746bc132 ce9b973e 98352838 ac9b713c 526515bd c1e86b44 4a48e460 d734e167 a1db4ea7 32d49c52 d42251e9 4e128f4a cec5b64a 0668c106 98251e94 a65048e2 9598ae32 e8edb694 ff00b247 f4a75b8d b6f10ff6 4532eff7 d0322705 b1d6a50e a1400380 3155f66c 47dab8d7 e4914d07 9a4de092 68dc3b52 b1aa1f4e 53cd37b0 3477a404 87ad1499 cd148433 68c9e28d a3d294f5 345318dd 83d28d83 d29d4517 01bb07a5 2141e94f a29dc08f 62fa5284 5f4a0f06 9475a63b 06c5f4a4 283d29c2 834ae2b0 cd8be94b b17d2945 2d1701bb 07a53c22 fa525381 a183008b e94bb578 e294506a 4914aaed 1c523801 09c529fb b4c90fca 0508490d c01da9b8 a70e6931 806a8d07 039e290f 5a13ad29 eb48428a 28145021 6928a290 05145140 c28a28a6 21ac2928 a299438f 6a0d1452 1094a28a 2980a00a 3bd14548 870a5345 14842f6a 8dbef0fa 51453408 41d283d0 d1453281 7a5068a2 80145145 14847fff d9"
```

Comment: What kind of image is this supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's strip spaces from your 'image code':

```
$hex =  preg_replace('/[\s\W]+/','',$image_code);
```

Convert the HEX string to binary:

```
$bin = pack("H*", $hex);
```

you can use `$bin = hex2bin($hex)` instead which is available since PHP 5.4.

Save it to disk:

```
   file_put_contents("file.jpg", $bin);
```

If you want to print image to a visitor in IMG tag you need to set the right header. Here's the full code will fit your request:

```
<?php

$res = "ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000001 00010000 ffe10058 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080002 01120003 00000001 00010000 87690004 00000001 00000026 00000000 0003a001 00030000 00010001 0000a002 00040000 00010000 00b7a003 00040000 00010000 01130000 0000ffdb 0043001f 15171b17 131f1b19 1b23211f 252f4e32 2f2b2b2f 5f444838 4e706376 746e636d 6b7c8cb2 977c84a9 866b6d9b d39da9b8 bec8cac8 7895dbea d9c2e9b2 c4c8c0ff db004301 2123232f 292f5b32 325bc080 6d80c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0 ffc00011 08011300 b7030122 00021101 031101ff c4001f00 00010501 01010101 01000000 00000000 00010203 04050607 08090a0b ffc400b5 10000201 03030204 03050504 04000001 7d010203 00041105 12213141 06135161 07227114 328191a1 082342b1 c11552d1 f0243362 7282090a 16171819 1a252627 28292a34 35363738 393a4344 45464748 494a5354 55565758 595a6364 65666768 696a7374 75767778 797a8384 85868788 898a9293 94959697 98999aa2 a3a4a5a6 a7a8a9aa b2b3b4b5 b6b7b8b9 bac2c3c4 c5c6c7c8 c9cad2d3 d4d5d6d7 d8d9dae1 e2e3e4e5 e6e7e8e9 eaf1f2f3 f4f5f6f7 f8f9faff c4001f01 00030101 01010101 01010100 00000000 00010203 04050607 08090a0b ffc400b5 11000201 02040403 04070504 04000102 77000102 03110405 21310612 41510761 71132232 81081442 91a1b1c1 09233352 f0156272 d10a1624 34e125f1 1718191a 26272829 2a353637 38393a43 44454647 48494a53 54555657 58595a63 64656667 68696a73 74757677 78797a82 83848586 8788898a 92939495 96979899 9aa2a3a4 a5a6a7a8 a9aab2b3 b4b5b6b7 b8b9bac2 c3c4c5c6 c7c8c9ca d2d3d4d5 d6d7d8d9 dae2e3e4 e5e6e7e8 e9eaf2f3 f4f5f6f7 f8f9faff da000c03 01000211 0311003f 00b19eb4 72693bd2 e715e69d e3581eb4 ca909183 9a8f7814 d1485cd2 37ad0181 a5c03d0d 03114f51 4ea60e09 a750c181 e2941cf7 a3ad3738 a0438e71 d6929339 a5e9400b 9a01a6e6 941a007e 683c814d cd283c52 1587034a 0d3334a0 d2b0587e 68cd3734 668b1361 f9a4cd37 34668b05 87834522 d1482c33 bd213413 8269339a b2ac3189 27148571 413f39a7 70453d8b d8414872 18114a69 2801cfd8 d0a78a5c 82829838 24502241 4845028a 421a2969 31834b4c 6252d068 a005a514 94aa6908 3bd28a3b d28a4214 518a052d 21011494 1349400f 5a2901a2 908818f2 28191cf6 a4ee28dc 73ed5a1a d843c1cd 3c74a691 8fa53802 7a1a0043 49d29d83 8a6edf5a 00543c11 41e0e69c 00148c28 175014b4 d534ea42 03cd140a 28010d14 1a4a6316 94525148 079a01a4 cd20340a c3c52d34 1aad772e d9ed9075 69013446 3ccec437 6572d9a6 d29a4a45 0e5a2901 a290885c 60f1498f ce9ed8a6 f5ab4688 07229ca7 d3a54609 cf14f4ea 6860d0f3 4de69dda 9bda9225 0a2918f1 4134839a 63105283 4838cd28 a062e697 3c52639a 5c5210d2 69334a45 25318b9a 5078a402 940a0426 6968c669 39a0082d e6f32ee7 50785c01 f866a0b8 491f5588 81903047 3d81a7d8 41b1e57d c4e58afd 79eb52a7 3a931fee c607eb5b 68a4edd8 c2cdc55c 75fcbe55 b120f3b8 0fd7ff00 ad56322a 9ea51f99 0280c00d c3fc2ad2 a954504e 480013eb 59b4b951 6afccc70 eb4520eb 456650d6 19cd3706 9f9eb484 815450d0 bcd39570 734020d2 64f6a007 938a4269 393d69b9 228b0580 9eb403c0 34d39c9a 51ca914c ab0a4e68 14514843 bb538532 941a4215 864532a4 a611834d 02014ea6 d3a860c5 a46e067d 28a493fd 5b7fba68 5b8886cf 3f664cf5 6c93f9d3 6dce6f2e 5bdd47e9 4eb5c1b5 888fee8a 65972666 fef486b4 7f688ec3 af8e215f f7d6ad1e f54efcfe e93feba0 ab879a99 7c2817c4 c41d68a0 75a2a0b1 99c9a08a 4e99a0e4 1eb4ca17 818a3238 a6d2d301 770a0e08 a6d0093c 668b0584 6e99a14f 38a18522 f514c7d0 9074a314 8bde9d52 2128a5a3 140828eb 45250014 b4845283 400a2834 8294d211 4d924b46 2f082f0f 564f4fa5 436734cd 16c8a3c9 c925d8f0 2af5c36d b790e7f8 4d4361ff 001e71e3 be7f9d6e a5eedda3 2e5f7ac9 8b1db664 124ce646 1d07402a da93c834 c14f5ac6 4dbdcd2c 96c263e6 a29d8ef4 5485c889 c838a652 b37b5039 15668252 e6942123 ad326262 85dc63e5 19e685ae 826d21a5 f3208d7a fde6f614 bbf32151 d57a9f4a ab14a61b 27b86199 246e0ff9 fc6acda2 05b6539c 96f989f5 26b4946c 8ce33bb1 dcfad006 0d29e28a 8351475a 7d3053aa 5898b40a 2814085a 4a534948 418a08a0 52d031bd 29683473 4c0af7c0 1b39323a 723eb4b6 b188ed90 01d464fd 4d33516f f4461dc9 02ac0015 40ec062a fec5884b df147515 20a881e6 9e1866a1 a2da2414 535ba0c5 1524d880 f24d3929 31c93403 5668c93a 552d565d b6e101e5 cfe82ae0 358faa49 bee76f64 18aba4af 230aaed1 2179d9e0 8e2fe14c fe35b501 06de323a 6d1fcab0 2b5f4e94 3da85279 4e3f0ada ac74d0ca 8cbdeb32 c1a4cd29 39a415ce 760a29c0 d3694526 0c7d0290 1a514891 dda9b4e1 4d348414 b494b40c 4a28a298 152ffe6f 253fbd20 ab2dcd56 b9e6f6d9 7d096ff3 f9559356 f644c7e2 6369d494 f032054b 2d8f4e94 50bc5150 410f7a43 9a53de92 acd00356 1ccfbe67 7fef126b 6663b627 6f4526b0 eba28add 9cb887b2 12ac5a4f e44d93f7 4f06abd1 5b357563 993b3ba3 7f208c83 c5159f63 74001148 78fe127b 7b5680eb 5c928b8b 3d184d4d 5c5a052d 15050a29 d4d155cd d2457322 4a768c0d bc53516f 622524b7 2d8a0d41 f6cb6c67 ce5fd6a4 49125526 360c3da9 38b5ba12 927b31d4 52640ea6 96914145 14500546 f9b535ff 0062327f cfe7564d 568b9d46 63fdd503 f9559357 3e84c3ab 129ebd29 94e4a865 b245eb45 20eb4549 2447ad25 29ef4559 64178716 b21f6c7e b58b5b37 fc5a3fe1 fceb1aba a8ec71e2 3e20a28a 2b539c2b 42cef318 8e53c766 359f4b53 28a92b32 e1371774 7418a2b3 6cefb601 1cc72bd8 fa569020 ae41c83d 08ae4945 c59db09a 9a1b2c82 289a43fc 23f3ac49 64695cbb 9c935a5a 993f65e3 a6e19fd6 b3a011b4 ca262c10 f04af5ad e8a56b9c f5dbbd88 aa48a578 5c3a1c11 51d15b1c fb1b16ed 3dcc8934 80246b92 00ee7a55 ca8ad062 d2218c7c a2a5ae19 bbb3be0a c828a08a 31525952 d399ee5f d5f1fcea cd56d3f2 6066fef3 93564d5c fe2269fc 2253969b 4e5a865b 1e28a406 8a449193 cd148472 68ab2caf a87fc7a3 fe1fceb1 eb66f866 ce4fc3f9 d63574d2 f84e2c47 c4145145 6a601453 954b3055 0493d00a b8b64b1a 6fb87c01 d8526d22 a3072d8a 35620bb9 200429c8 f43d2a39 4a17cc6a 557d09cd 4745935a 8aee2f42 dcb7cf2c 65191307 eb55475a 2b52d6d2 17b552cb 92dce7d2 a5b5045a 52a8ccc7 fbedf5a7 40a1e644 6ce1980e 2a5bcb66 82439e54 9e0fad59 b1b35788 c920fbdf 7483c8a1 c925708c 1b958d25 50a00030 070297bd 26ee9eb4 a01cf35c 4ced0351 cceb1c4c cc71c1eb 505edf2d bfc89f34 9fa0ac87 91a4625d 8927d6b6 8526f566 33aa9688 d3b1b885 2048cbe1 8f6c1f5a b84562d9 297bb8c0 3d0e7f2a da345549 3d0aa326 d6a369cb 4def4e5a c99b31e2 8a051522 233d4d21 14eee692 a8a2bddf 36b20f6f eb58d5b7 723f7127 fba6b12b a68ec71e 23e20a5a 4a9ada3f 36e114f4 cf3f4ad9 e86095dd 8bd6b12d b41e749f 788cfd07 a5519ee1 e76cb1e3 b0ab3a9c 80b2a03c af26a8d6 7057f799 ad495bdc 42514558 86d2594f dd2abea6 adb4b732 49bd8af5 66d2e9e0 61ce533c 8a5bdb71 038dbf74 8fd6aad1 a490f583 3a170b2a 00406523 f3a6c508 8576a93b 3b03dbf1 a8f4f7df 68a3392b c1a65c5f a43f2a0d edfa0ae4 e595dc51 d9cd1b73 32d9c05c 93803b9a a571a905 f9201b9b fbddaa93 49717920 4c96cf45 1d05695a 59adbf27 e693d7d3 e955c918 6b2239dc f48ec52f b05d4ca6 520658e4 863834c9 6c64862f 31caf500 01cd6e0e 473552f9 4b889077 9067e94e 355b7625 d2495c2d ad52d94e 0ee63d49 a9a9cdde 92b16db7 76744524 ac86914e 02928148 a1c33452 8e68a421 87a9a4a5 ef495450 c9c66171 fec9fe55 855bec32 8c3d462b 00d7451d 99c988dd 0956f4d0 0dce4f65 3552ad69 fccac338 ca919ad6 5b18c3e2 4433bf99 33bfa926 a3a5a4aa 25bbb2d5 82a35c80 e33dc7d6 b56b1219 1a2903af 515b1e6a 08c3b305 52323358 554ee755 092b5826 89668ca3 7e07d0d6 52a886e7 6ccb900e 1aaec9a8 c438452d fa551b99 84f26fdb b4e31d69 d3525a32 6b4a0f55 b8095a16 758643b5 b8cfa8a6 22867019 c20ee4d3 6ad595aa 5c87dcc4 15c74ad5 b495cc12 72762f5a c96902e2 39173dc9 ea6a7fb4 c19ff5c9 ff007d55 5fecc87f bcff00a5 4173a734 519911b7 28ec7ad7 35a127b9 d379c56c 69adcc1d e64ffbe8 526a1f68 b758de30 5075debc fe07fcf3 5cfd5cb4 d4ee2d57 cb0c248b bc6e323f fad5a2a4 a2ee8c9d 5bee6a45 2f9f0972 9b1c1c36 3a13ed4e a8e2984d 1aba26c5 3d17d29e 2b09ee75 4360a050 692a4b24 534522d1 52219de8 a3bd1545 0b58128d b2b2fa13 5bd59175 11379281 eedfd6b7 a2f739b1 0ae910c0 9e6cc89e a715a6d1 088ccca3 00a71ec4 0aaf6701 570ec391 b48fa1ab 1a84de5c 2507de7e 3e82aa4d b92489a7 1518b6cc 8a28a2b6 39829c58 9c64938e 29b45001 45153456 d2cbf754 e3d4f028 ba5b8d26 f6220093 81d6b66c adbc88be 61f337de f6a6dad9 2c243b7c cffa0ab7 5cd52a5f 447552a5 cbab1401 e9f9d2fd 69052d73 9b19f3e9 9be5cc4c 154f507b 532dacd1 6ea4493e 70807b73 5a847a55 3b6e6e2e 5bfdbc56 f1a92716 64e9c799 163000c0 1c519a28 c5646e19 a438a28c 500286a2 900a281d 83b9a28e e68a002a 9cd1e6f5 b8fbf11f e5572a29 07fa4c4d fef0fd2a e0eccce6 ae84b5c1 b78ce39d b8fcab3e 7dd737e5 01efb47b 015a36e3 623274da c40fa75a a48047aa e3b127f5 15a45ead 99cd7bb1 45c16f12 c7b0202b efdea336 5013f731 f426acd2 1acd49f7 36e48f63 1ae1424e caabb403 c0a2081e 77c2f4ee 7d29f7ae b25c92a7 20719f5a d1b6458e dd00ee32 4d744a7c b1b9c90a 6a536848 ad618ba2 ee3ea79a 9e929472 2b99b6f7 3b14525a 0e14a29a 29d50028 a514de94 aa726810 f1daa958 730bbff7 a426adbb 011b927a 026abd82 e2ca3f7c 9fd6aa3a 4599fda4 4d494360 52039a46 a2d28008 3494e5e2 93062628 a0f5a280 1a7a9a2a a6268f88 e5dc3d1c 7f5a5fb4 4e3ac00f fbad5a72 76279fba 2d66908c 907d0e6a b7da64ff 009f739f f7850679 cf48957f de6cff00 2a395873 a2c10a85 9c9c0c73 9f6acf83 371a8194 0c2af3fe 1523c4f3 1fdf4a48 feea8c0a 9e32912e d45c0abf 857990d3 9357d89b 35535079 950041f2 1eac2a7f 347a5233 864618ea 08a88e8e e5cd5d59 18b566de f1a11b48 dcbe9e95 098641d5 1bf2a4f2 dffba7f2 aeb766ac ce14e517 746bc132 ce9b973e 98352838 ac9b713c 526515bd c1e86b44 4a48e460 d734e167 a1db4ea7 32d49c52 d42251e9 4e128f4a cec5b64a 0668c106 98251e94 a65048e2 9598ae32 e8edb694 ff00b247 f4a75b8d b6f10ff6 4532eff7 d0322705 b1d6a50e a1400380 3155f66c 47dab8d7 e4914d07 9a4de092 68dc3b52 b1aa1f4e 53cd37b0 3477a404 87ad1499 cd148433 68c9e28d a3d294f5 345318dd 83d28d83 d29d4517 01bb07a5 2141e94f a29dc08f 62fa5284 5f4a0f06 9475a63b 06c5f4a4 283d29c2 834ae2b0 cd8be94b b17d2945 2d1701bb 07a53c22 fa525381 a183008b e94bb578 e294506a 4914aaed 1c523801 09c529fb b4c90fca 0508490d c01da9b8 a70e6931 806a8d07 039e290f 5a13ad29 eb48428a 28145021 6928a290 05145140 c28a28a6 21ac2928 a299438f 6a0d1452 1094a28a 2980a00a 3bd14548 870a5345 14842f6a 8dbef0fa 51453408 41d283d0 d1453281 7a5068a2 80145145 14847fff d9";

$hex =  preg_replace('/[\s\W]+/','',$res);
$binary = pack("H*", $hex);
header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
print $binary;
?>
```

Comment: Hello KennyPowers, This way I think I have to upload my image on my server. I don't want to upload my image on server. I just want to pass my image data in HTML <img> in an email template

Comment: I've changed my reply, hope it will help you.

Comment: @Hardik Works just fine for me (it's a little devil with an iPod or similar). You'll need to create a tag that uses the above PHP file, eg `<img src="path/to/the/above/file.php">`

Comment: Okay fine Sorry. Its a little small problem from my side. Your code is working perfectly for me. Thanks for you kind help :)